How is the scrollbar of the ListView determined?
I'm working with WinUI 3 C# and want to implement Random Access Data Virtualization in a ListView. I understand that this functionality is supported by default, but instead of using an in-memory array, I want to fetch data dynamically from another source and display only a portion at a time.
I referred to the following documentation and implemented a class using IItemsRangeInfo:
Random access data virtualization documentation.
Question. I would like to set the total size of the scrollbars to 10000, but they end up changing size to match the actual display. The documentation says it will be the total size, but what if I want the scrollbars to be the total size when virtualizing with ListView?

C#
  public class ObservableRangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IItemsRangeInfo
  {
    private int _totalCount = 10000; 
    private int _startIndex;
    private int _endIndex;

    public int TotalCount
    {
      get => _totalCount;
      set
      {
        if( _totalCount != value )
        {
          _totalCount = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof( TotalCount ) ) );
        }
      }
    }

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public void LoadItems( int startIndex, int count )
    {
      this.Clear();

      //  Load Data Simulation
      for( int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count && i < _totalCount; i++ )
      {
        this.Add( (T)(object)(new SampleData( i )) );
      }

      OnCollectionChanged( new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs( NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset ) );
    }

    public void RangesChanged( ItemIndexRange visibleRange, IReadOnlyList<ItemIndexRange> trackedItems )
    {
      if( visibleRange.FirstIndex != _startIndex && visibleRange.LastIndex != _endIndex )
      {
        _startIndex = visibleRange.FirstIndex;
        _endIndex = visibleRange.LastIndex;

        Debug.WriteLine( $"RangeIndex: {_startIndex} , {_endIndex}" );
        this.LoadItems( visibleRange.FirstIndex, _endIndex - _startIndex + 1 );
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }


C# UserControl
public MyUserControl()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  
  Items = new ObservableRangeCollection<SampleData>();

  try
  {
    Items.LoadItems( 0, 5 );
    MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
  }
  catch( FormatException ex )
  {
  }
}

Xaml
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        IsItemClickEnabled="False"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SampleData">
          <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Phase="0" Text="{x:Bind Id}"/>
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


Whether you want to make the scrollbar reflect the full content size instead of actual display? You could try to create a custom VirtualizingStackPanel and then use the MeasureOverride to set the size of the custom Panel. The total size is manually calculated based on the number of items and their height.

Thank you for your advice. After checking various things, I found that by inheriting from IList and making the Count property reflect the total size, the scrollbar now always corresponds to the total size. However, virtualization using IItemsRangeInfo is not going very well. Managing the cache is extremely difficult, and I'm struggling because there is no information available at all :(
